# Getting "common name invalid" in Chrome with a self-signed certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I've added the CA certificate to Chrome trusted authorities list so it accepts the authority. But there is still a problem with the names:

`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

I've set CN to the IP address and added a Subject Alternative Name with the same value. I've tried CN-only too.

Why is it failing?

Comment: What type of SAN? dNSName or iPAddress? And you access the site by IP address and not a hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I had to generate Subject Alternative Name with `IP:` instead of `DNS:`.